# Single Spring context in jUnit tests

Tags: java, spring, configuration, junit

I've read a lot of advises on this topic but it seems that none of them work.
Currently application context is created for every test class but I want it to be created only once and be used by all test classes.

This is my test suite setup:

```
@RunWith(ClasspathSuite.class)
@ClassnameFilters({"org.*", ".*Test"})
public class AllTests {
}
```

This is my abstract class with context setup. All test classes are extending this class.

```
@TestExecutionListeners({DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class})
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {ServiceInitializer.Config.class})
@DirtiesContext
public abstract class ServiceInitializer extends AbstractJUnit4SpringContextTests {

@Configuration
@Import({TestConfig.class, SpringClientConfig.class})
public static class Config {
    @Bean
    public ContactsClient contactsClient(ContactsService contactsService) {
        return new ContactsClientFactory().createInstance(contactsService);         
    }
}

@Autowired
protected ContactsClient contactsService;

...

@Autowired
protected ApplicationContext appContext;


@BeforeClass
public static void setUpBeforeClass() throws Exception {
    initializeDB();
    initializeApplicationServiceProperties();
    dbInit = false;
}

protected static void initializeDB() throws Exception {
    ... database settings ...

    dropSQLTestDatabase(dbName, jdbcProperties);
    dropTestDatabase();
}

protected static void initializeApplicationServiceProperties() throws IOException {

    System.setProperty("log4j.config.file", ServiceInitializer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("log4j-test.xml").getFile());
    System.setProperty("app.config.file", ServiceInitializer.class.getClassLoader().getResource("test.properties").getFile());

    AppStartSupport.configureLogging();
    AppStartSupport.loadProperties();

}

...
}
```

Does anyone know how to change this setup in order to achieve single context that will be used by all jUnit tests?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this is by setting the *forkCount* property of maven surefire plugin to 1 (if you are running the junit tests through maven surfire plugin), or not specifying it at all in the plugin declaraton in your POM file, as the default value is 1. This would cause the application context to be loaded only once. In this case, you need to make sure you clean up the context after tests which modifies it.

```
..
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.16</version>
                <dependencies>
                </dependencies>
                <configuration>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Test.java</include>
                    </includes>
                    <forkCount>1</forkCount>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
..
```